# Checkpoint Validate non existence of Object

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

We are testing an GUI with UFT 14.52. For each Popup, Schema, View we have an single Component. I would like to add validations points for each component, so i can validate that the application is in the right state.

For Example:
I do have this Popup and an Component which handles the Popup (selecting street, and clicking buttons).

[image: Popup]

When the Component starts, i want to verify that the Popup is up. With UFT Checkpoints this works flawless by using enabled as identification.

[image: enabled as identification]

But if i want an verification point at the end (Check if the Popup is closed via enabled) i do get an "object not found exception from uft" as expected, because the given popup is closed. Validing the object is not existing by `JavaObject.Exist(5)` is not feasible because it will actually wait the timeout and then return the state.

Is there any workaround for this? Is there something similar as `javaObject.NonExists(5)`? Is this state validation at the end even useful?

Comment: `If Not javaObject.Exist(5) Then` should work for your requirement

Comment: @Dave a negation of javaObject.Exist(5) wont work because the script will actually wait 5 seconds and after this returns false (and then get negated by not). So the explicit wait will get converted to an implizit wait...

Comment: Yep - that's right.  `Exist` is boolean and tests for both conditions (true = it's there and false = it's not) so there's no such thing as a `Nonexist` - it is essentially the same thing as `Exist` with a different name.  If all you want is to speed things up, maybe reduce the wait to half a second if you're not expecting the object to be present

Comment: `Exist` will return either once the object is found or after the timeout elapses (whichever comes first) if you want to check if the object exists without waiting just pass `0` as the timeout. As @Dave said, there's no logical need for `NotExist`. Perhaps we've misunderstood the question, if so please try to clarify.

Comment: Do you mean that the object exists and you want to give it 5 seconds in which to cease to exist?

Comment: @Motti i didnt thought about passing 0 as timeout. gonna check that out. Thank you

Comment: I just finished writing an answer assuming your question is more complex :( Well I'll add the `Exist(0)` and leave it in case it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to note is that the timeout parameter to `Exist` doesn't default to zero, so if you want it to return right away if the object doesn't exist you should use `obj.Exist(0)`.

If my understanding is correct, you want to mimic the behaviour of `Exist` so that if the condition fails (the object *does* exist in this case) then the function doesn't return `False` immediately but waits the timeout for it to become `True` (for the object **not** to exist).

If so you can try this:

```
Public Function NotExist(ByRef test_object, ByVal timeout)
       Deadline = DateAdd("s", timeout, Now)
       While test_object.Exist(0)
            If DateDiff("s", Now, Deadline) < 0 Then
                NotExist = False
                Exit Function
            End If  
            test_object.RefreshObject ' not sure if this is needed
       Wend

       NotExist = True
End Function
RegisterUserFunc "JavaObject", "NotExist", "NotExist"
```

The only subtle part here is the `RefreshObject` which I thought was needed but it worked without it when I tried it with **Web addin** (I don't use Java).

I think it should be needed since UFT caches the object if it's found but perhaps `Exist` clears this cache (further reading on this [caching mechanism](https://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2018/09/20/how-uft-identifies-objects/)).